# How can we use xsl:function in xsl:when

Tags: java, xslt

Problem is that i need to test a state multiple times with xsl:when and i want to use a xsl:function like this

```
<xsl:function name="isPrime">
    <xsl:param name="var1"/>
    <xsl:param name="var2"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$var1='0' and $var2=1"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:when test="isPrime($var1, $var2)">
....
<xsl:when test="isPrime($var1, $var2)">
....
<xsl:when test="isPrime($var1, $var2)">
```

is there a way to do this? or is there a work around for a problem like this?

Comment: The problem isn't that you need X or that you want Y, the problem is that something is failing. Tell us how it fails.

Comment: Something is not failing. In my code, a long test case is repeating too much and i want my code to be more readable and rewritable

Comment: OK, that's already a better problem statement than we had before. But I think you've left out too much context to answer the question. Are those xsl:when elements in the same xsl:choose? In the same xsl:template? or scattered around the stylesheet all over the place?

Comment: i use it in multiple xsl files, i want to put the function on the header file then use it when i need it

Comment: There's no such thing as a header file but you can use xsl:include and xsl:import to import code in shared modules.

Comment: I know that, i use an xsl file as header in every other xsl file with include

Comment: It's very hard to know what you know since your question gave so little information about the actual nature of your problem, and when people use incorrect terminology we tend to assume they don't know much about the particular topic.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to below code snippet

```
<xsl:function name="isPrime">
    <xsl:param name="var1"/>
    <xsl:param name="var2"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="$var1='0' and $var2=1"/>
</xsl:function>
```

And then use the function

```
<xsl:variable name="return_value" select="{isPrime($var1, $var2)}"/>
<xsl:when test="{$return_value}">
```

Comment: the `<xsl:variable name="return_value" select="{isPrime($var1, $var2)}"/>` is wrong, should simply be `<xsl:variable name="return_value" select="isPrime($var1, $var2)"/>`, and the `xsl:when` simply `<xsl:when test="$return_value">`.